# I am using the library phonegap-nfc to scan nfc but when I scan it opens other page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, nfc

I'm using phonegap-nfc library in my vue project. Its working but I don't know why it open the information I have on my NFC car in other page information. What I want to do is show all the information that NFC have in my app. So if anyone knows how to do it could you help me please?

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-card-actions>
      <div class="cardInfos">
        {{ tagId }}
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',

  data: () => ({
    tagId: "",
    message: ""
  }),

  methods:{
    scanNFC(){
      window.nfc.enabled(
        () => {
          // NFC enabled
          this.registerTagEvent()
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error === 'NFC_DISABLED') {
            // Trigger the phone settings to enable the NFC settings
            window.nfc.showSettings()
          } else if (error === 'NO_NFC') {
            navigator.notification.alert('Cannot scan NFC', () => {}, 'No NFC', 'OK')
          }
        }
      )
    },

    registerTagEvent () {
      window.nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
        this.displayNdef,
        () => {
          console.log('succeess registering ndef listener')
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('failure registering ndef listener', error)
        }
      )
    },

    displayNdef (nfcEvent) {
      // Decode tag data from the plugin
        const bgColor = document.getElementsByClassName(".v-application--wrap")
        bgColor.style.backgroudColor = "green"
        let tag = nfcEvent.tag
        let tagId = window.nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id)
        let message = window.nfc.bytesToString(tag.ndefMessage[0].payload)
        this.tagId = tagId
        this.message = message

        window.ndefMessage(tagId, message)
      }
    },

    deactivated () {
      this.unregisterTagEvent()
    },

    unregisterTagEvent () {
      // Test if the plugin is defined
      if ((typeof nfc) !== 'undefined') {
        window.nfc.removeNdefListener(this.displayNdef)
      }
    },
};
</script>
```

Can anyone help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with these steps:

Steps to disable Tags app on stock Android:

Navigate to Settings
Click on Apps & Notifications
Click on See all apps (Usually under Recently opened apps)
Click on 3 dots on top right hand
Click on Show system (which will enable all system installed apps)
Search for the app (default nfc app, which you will see in Choose options while reading NFC tag)
Usually the app is called Tags: click on Tags app in the list of apps
Click on Disable and click on OK on any dialogs which are displayed around disabling the app